# Mysql: one large select statement? or multiple small statements?

Tags: php, mysql

Just wondering what's best practice for the following in terms of efficiency.

I have a table called "blogPosts" with several fields. I also have a table called "comments" which contains a column blogPost_Id.

There could be many comments for one blog post.

I want to retrieve all information about all posts and all sub-comments, is it better to try and contain this in one sql command like this:

`SELECT * FROM blogPosts LEFT JOIN comments ON blogPosts.id = comments.blogPost_id`

or is it better to do `SELECT * from blogPosts`

and then do another `SELECT * from comments WHERE blogPost_id=postId` for every post?

I should add that I will be adding filters to the SQL based on post and comment fields.

Comment: Much better to get in once and out once imo...

Comment: Making only one select is more efficient.

Comment: Benchmark both options. Choose the faster one.

Comment: ok cheers, thats what I thought, but it means if there is 30 comments,  every row in my return seems to have repeated information of the post it belongs to. Does this mean all that info is being pulled every time a single comment is pulled?

Comment: @meagar is correct. Though I believe in the "one trip", it does depend on several things (database speed, connection to the database, size of the resultset (especially the size of the duplicate info you might retrieve)). Also available database connection. and other things. You should benchmark it.

Answer (score 3):

Connecting to the database is expensive. The less you do it, the better.

Another way to say it, what's faster? Making 1,000 trips to drop off 1,000 boxes or one trip to drop off 1,000 boxes?

Comment: When I execute one large query, each row in the return contains the comment information, and also the information of the parent post, so if I have 30 comments under the same post, the posts info is repeated 30 times. Is this info being pulled thirty times needlessly?

Comment: Then either there is a db design issue or these queries need t be separated. Using less queries is always a good idea but it doesn't mean that we can make it happen every time.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule less round trips to the database is better, so one giant query is normally preferred.

However, that's not a rule. Your query may actually be a lot slower if you don't set up your indexes properly. Another thing to look out for is the complexity and maintainability of your code. I once wrote a very complex query that joined about 17 tables. It was a nightmare to debug and modify.

Bench-marking is crucial as it's your only tool for measuring performance. You may actually find that sometimes splitting a query may improve performance.

As far as I can see, your query is simple enough to do the join in one query and get away with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm going to start bench marking see what suits best. The above statement was a simplified version of the actual task which will span across 5 or 6 tables

Answer (score 0):

For a simple query like the one in the question, let the database do the join.  There is no question about this.

There might be some discussion on more complex queries, but databases are designed for processing large amounts of data.  Trying to replicate the database work in an application is *not* represented.

That said, there are some cases where database optimizers/engines do get confused.  In such cases, creating temporary tables or doing work in the application may be necessary.  This is not a good thing, but reality.

Let the application layer do what the application layer does best.  Let the database do what the database does best, and this definitely includes processing the data.